# Why PyPy 1.7 desn't implement "stackless" stack?

Tags: continuations, pypy, python-stackless, tail-call-optimization, stackless

Default build of PyPy 1.7 with stackless included in, does not offer the ability to run with no recursion depth limit (in straight way).

**Why?**

Previus builds of PyPy with stackless support continuation style of function call and tail recursion.

I'm not asking about solutions involving coroutines, but the looking for the problems of integration stackelss.

Comment: http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/stackless.html seems to have a lot of information on this topic.

Comment: The question come after read it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason is that the new continulets work on the os level stack, which is limited
(however they are **much** more simple than the old stackless transform in the translation process)

there is a current work in progress for continulet jit that experiments with the stack being gc-managed blocks

if that is successfull, the "limitless" stack for stackless will be back in the form of just allocating new stack blocks till you run out of memeory